# Processing a list thats extracted from a CSV file from a URL

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, dictionary, file-handling

I'm trying to process data I've extracted from an online CSV file for a currency converter GUI application.
CSV file link :(https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.zip).

I've extracted the file and converted it from a string to a list using split(), what I'm trying to do next is to make a dictionary for each currency with the dates being the keys and the conversion rates being the values of the keys.

Example of how I want the dictionary to be:

```
USD: {
      (2018, 10, 8): 1.1478, 
      (2018, 10, 5): 1.1506, 
      (2018, 10, 4): 1.1502, 
      (2018, 10, 3): 1.1548, 
      (2018, 10, 2): 1.1543, 
      ...}
```

I need to use this dictionary with the my PyQt5 widgets so I can perform the conversion and update the widgets.

Libraries used in Application:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QComboBox, QDoubleSpinBox, QCalendarWidget, QDialog, QApplication, QGridLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from decimal import Decimal
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import zipfile
import pyqtgraph as pg
```

The code i used to unzip the folder and convert it to a list:

```
self.data = {} 
url = 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.zip'  
self.file, _ = urlretrieve(url)
zip_file_object = zipfile.ZipFile(self.file, 'r')
first_file = zip_file_object.namelist()[0]
self.file = zip_file_object.open(first_file)
content = self.file.read().decode()
lst = []
lst = content.split(",")
```

Note: This was made using an Anaconda virtual enviroment

Answer (score 1):

Improving @codingatty's answer:

```
import csv
f = open("eurofxref-hist.csv")
csvreader = csv.reader(f)
header_row = next(csvreader)
currencies = header_row[1:]
all_currencies_dict = {}

for currency in currencies:
    all_currencies_dict[currency] = {}

for data_row in csvreader:
    date = data_row.pop(0)
    date_tuple = tuple(date.split("-"))
    for i, currency in enumerate(currencies):
        if data_row[i] != 'N/A':
            currency_dict = all_currencies_dict[currency]
            currency_dict[date_tuple] = data_row[i]

print(all_currencies_dict["USD"])
```

Comment: Dude, you just altered my answer!

Comment: Why to re-invent the wheel ? It's a better version for your answer !! I hope you understand the difference between the two

Comment: You should at least acknowledge where you took your base from.

Comment: Right, sorry for that. Added a line for that now.

Comment: I don't think it's a better answer. Yes, it removes "N/A" data, but that's not something the poster asked for, and I prefer not to guess whether he wants the program to be just drop parts of the data. It might be better to keep it as None, for example.

And yes, it uses enumerate(), but as I said, I was deliberately a bit verbose for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, all you need from this is that dictionary you mentioned. I've added comments to my answer here so you can follow what I did

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/abhishekbabuji/Downloads/eurofxref-hist.csv")
df1 = df.copy() #Create copy of df
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']) #Convert the 'Date' column in to datetime 

df1['Year'] = df1['Date'].dt.year #Creating seperate column containing year portion
df1['Month'] = df1['Date'].dt.month #Creating seperate column containing month portion
df1['Day'] = df1['Date'].dt.day #Creating seperate column containing day portion

df1['YMD'] = df1[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']].apply(tuple, axis=1) #Zipping these three into a tuple
USD = dict(zip(df1['YMD'],df1['USD'])) #Creating a dictionary with the tuple as key, and values are the rows in column named 'USD'
```

and now:

```
print(USD)
```

gives:

```
{(2018, 10, 12): 1.1574,
 (2018, 10, 11): 1.1575,
 (2018, 10, 10): 1.15,
 (2018, 10, 9): 1.1435,
 (2018, 10, 8): 1.1478,
 (2018, 10, 5): 1.1506,
 (2018, 10, 4): 1.1502,
 (2018, 10, 3): 1.1548,
 (2018, 10, 2): 1.1543,
 .
 .
 .}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the built-in `csv` module, and use the header line to set keys for a dictionary of your currencies, and then populate with the data rows, rather than try to glom through the full file in one string.

The below reads the CSV file directly, but you can adapt it to download and unzip the file; you already have that part down. A little bit verbose for clarity. (Python3; the `next` syntax is different for Python2, but should also work.)

```
import csv

INFILE = "eurofxref-hist.csv"
f = open(INFILE)
csvreader = csv.reader(f)
header_row = next(csvreader)
currencies = header_row[1:] # remove the "Date" header entry; we want only the currencies
all_currencies_dict = {}
for currency in currencies:
    all_currencies_dict[currency] = {}
for data_row in csvreader:
    date = data_row.pop(0) # remove but save date
    date_tuple = tuple(date.split("-"))
    for i in range(0, len(currencies)):
        currency = currencies[i]
        currency_dict = all_currencies_dict[currency]
        conversion = data_row[i]
        currency_dict[date_tuple] = conversion
# remove empty entry resulting from spurious comma at end of each row:
del all_currencies_dict[""]
```

Now you have a dict of dicts, one for each currency.

```
print(all_currencies_dict["USD"])
```

will print (formatted for clarity):

```
{('2018', '10', '12'): '1.1574', 
('2018', '10', '11'): '1.1575',
 ...}
```

Comment: As I said in my comment above to Vishvajit, this doesn't attempt to delete or alter any of your data, which you may want to do. However, one thing I did note is that each row of your data includes a spurious comma at the end, and that means there's a final zero-length string on the end of each row, which will be dutifully added to the dict. I've added a line to account for that and delete the empty dict it adds.